# Vídeo como Background HTML 5 não funciona no Safari e Chrome no Mac

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, html5-video

Eu coloquei um vídeo como background de um site com HTML 5, eu abro no Chrome e no Firefox no Windows e o vídeo rola normal, mas quando eu abro no Mac (Chrome versão 67.0.3396.40, e Safari 11.1) o vídeo não rola... Alguém conhece alguma solução?

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
                <div class="bg-video">
                    <video autoplay loop src="images/video-serv.mp4"></video>
                </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap {
    /*Ajuste a largura e altura desejadas aqui*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    /*isto fará o elemento video e o .container se adaptarem ao .wrap*/
    position: relative;
}
.wrap > .bg-video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1; /*apenas um -1 é necessário quando se trabalha com relative + absolute, sendo pai e filho*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; /* evita do video passar a altura desejada do .wrap */
}
.wrap > .bg-video > video {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thayna eu não tenho um Mac aqui para testar, mas a sua tag do `video` pode ser construída com o `source` dentro da tag `video`, o que é mais adequado. Pode ser que assim funcione no Mac..., mas como falei aqui não tenho como testar ness plataforma.

Outro detalhe, troque teste trocando o position:absolute por relative, nessa classe `.wrap > .bg-video { position: relative; ....}`

```css
.wrap {
    /*Ajuste a largura e altura desejadas aqui*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

    /*isto fará o elemento video e o .container se adaptarem ao .wrap*/
    position: relative;
}
.wrap > .bg-video {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1; /*apenas um -1 é necessário quando se trabalha com relative + absolute, sendo pai e filho*/
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; /* evita do video passar a altura desejada do .wrap */
}
.wrap > .bg-video > video {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="bg-video">
        <video autoplay loop>
            <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4"  />
        </video>
    </div>
</div>
```

Aqui tem alguns exemplos de uso da tag `video`, vc pode inclusive testar no Mac https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp

Comment: Oi Hugo, eu coloquei a source dentro da tag video e funcionou no safari e no firefox no Mac, mas no Chrome ainda não está funcionando...

Comment: Vc está pelo menos escutando o som no Chrome, ou nem isso? Se o som estiver aparecendo muito provavelmente o seu vídeo está lá, mas esta oculta fora da área visível ou atras de outro elemento...

Comment: O vídeo que eu estou usando não tem som... vou fazer um teste com algum vídeo com som.

Comment: O vídeo com som não funcionou também e não dá pra escutar o som no Chrome... É muito estranho nos outros navegadores funcionaram normal e no Chrome do Windows também.

Comment: Oiii, consegui arrumar! eu deixei o HTML somente com a Tag vídeo assim:
<video autoplay muted loop id="myVideo">
        <source src="images/video-serv.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

E o CSS assim:

#myVideo {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%;
}

E funcionou... acho que o meu css anterior estava influenciando em alguma coisa... Obrigada pela a ajuda :)

Comment: @ThaynaRocha Pois é eu estava desconfiado que seria o CSS, o problema é que não tenho um Mac em mãos para fazer esses testes rss, Mas que bom que resolveu! Só um coisa, se vc usou `position:fixed` não deixe de testar no iPhone, pois até um tempo atras esse tipo de position não costumava funcionar bem no Safari, dps faz o teste lá se sua página precisar ser mobile tb